# Process substitution with diff and pipes

Tags: command-line, bash, diff

When checking if a key and crt match I usually compare the hashes of the modulus as so:

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in key.key | openssl md5
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in crt.crt | openssl md5
```

this obviously depends on visibly comparing the two hashes which is not ideal.

I tried to use diff with process substitution

```
diff <(openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in key.key | openssl md5) <(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in crt.crt | openssl md5)
```

but it seems like process substitution does not work with pipes. Hold on, can't I nest the hashing with another substitution?

```
diff <(openssl md5 <(openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in key.key)) <(openssl md5 <(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in crt.crt))
```

which works but the diff (or comm) will always detect a difference because the values compared are

> MD5(/dev/fd/63)= 0bf775063be9c69057747c15bf723786             | MD5(/dev/fd/62)= 0bf775063be9c69057747c15bf723786

Comment: In what way exactly does it seem *"like process substitution does not work with pipes"*?

Comment: It looks like in your first `diff` command, you were expecting some output, but `diff` does not output anything when there is no difference. So: au contraire, process substitution with pipes did work in that example, and worked perfectly, since there was no spurious difference in the output to confuse diff.

Comment: did you mean this? `diff <<<"$(openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in key.key | openssl md5)" <<<"$(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in crt.crt | openssl md5)"`

Comment: @muru the output for the command with pipes is

`diff: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
diff: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory`

Comment: @lnee this does not work, no operand after diff

Comment: @Vulkanodox I cannot reproduce that. Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @muru it was a sudo problem, I figured it out.  Doing it as root solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why my own answer was deleted but the solution was:

It works with the pipes as stated by muru there was some problem with sudo.

Running the command without a sudo command but as root it works

Comment: You should have mentioned in the question that you were using `sudo`.

Comment: @muru fair point but why delete the answer then?

Comment: No idea, I wasn't involved in that. Probably it looked like you were posting a comment

Answer (score 0):

So diff can not take in pipes like this `diff <<<"some st" <<<"some sy"`,
but can do this `diff file <<<"some sy"` so this function will help

```
dubdiff(){
arg1="$(mktemp)"
arg2="$(mktemp)"
eval "$1" > "$arg1"
eval "$2" > "$arg2"
diff "$arg1" "$arg2"
rm "$arg1" "$arg2"
}
```

It will run the first command and put it in a file same for the secent one and diffs them so run `dubdiff 'openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in key.key | openssl md5' 'openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in crt.crt | openssl md5'`

Comment: Yes, but a short script would also do the same at that point. I was more interested in solving the simple one-line command as it seems it is pretty close to doing what I'm looking for

Comment: does it work or do i need to fix it?

Comment: works perfectly